# How to delete HTML from excerpts in posts on homepage?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How Can I delete html tags in excerpts posts on homepage https://ptbo.edu.pl/ ?

**I mean only HOMEPAGE** (not in categories) because I'm changing this manually in posts editor.

My code looks now:

```
<?php if ( allium_has_excerpt() ) : ?>
            <div class="entry-summary">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
            <?php endif; ?>
```

I want to make changes only on the home page

Comment: This could be achieved using JS. I did not really understand what you re trying to achieve. Do you want the HTML tags to disappear inside entry-summary? Or do you want the entry-summary also to be non-existent, so the text is inside another div?

Comment: I want delete html tags, like a hrefs.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to leave the HTML tags but add this CSS to make them unnoticeable:

```
.home .entry-summary a {
pointer-events: none;
color: #3d3d3d;
}

.home .entry-summary strong {
font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: No. Solution by CSS is not good idea (SEO).